# How to pass data in a jsp file to multiple servlet using javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp file which has a form. And the form has some text fields and image upload field.I need to send text data to one servlet and image to another servlet when I click the submit button. is this possible ?

[image]

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. I think it is possible .. the way I know you have to use a javascript library like jquery. Below is how it happens

On form submit you prevent the post to servlet. Then you can use ajax like shown below to send 2 requests to 2 different servlets. Below shows one ajax call.. you can do another after that call. I trying to show you below

```
$("form").submit(function(evt){  
      evt.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      var author = $("#author").val();
   $.ajax({
       url: 'fileUploadServletUrl',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       processData: false,
       success: function (response) {
         alert(response);
       }
   });

   $.ajax({
       url: 'textDataServletUrl',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {'author':author },
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (response) {
         alert(response);
       }
   });

   return false;
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much Paul :)

Comment: cool ! Happy to help. If this works for you please mark the answer as correct.